# Changing Spinner list content after item is selected Android

Tags: android, spinner, android-adapter, onitemclicklistener, onitemselectedlistener

Is there a way to change the displayed list inside of the `Spinner` after selection. I have 2 `Strings`, `English` and `Finnish` and I want to first change their language when one is selected, secondly change their order when the other is selected.

```
private void initLanguageSpinner() {

    List<String> spinnerLocale = new ArrayList<>();
    if ((currentdocumentLocale.toString().startsWith("deviceNameFi") || currentdocumentLocale.getLanguage().equals("fi"))) {
        spinnerLocale.add(getLocalizedResources(context, currentdocumentLocale).getString(R.string.finnish_language));
        spinnerLocale.add(getLocalizedResources(context, currentdocumentLocale).getString(R.string.english_language));
    } else {
        spinnerLocale.add(getLocalizedResources(context, currentdocumentLocale).getString(R.string.english_language));
        spinnerLocale.add(getLocalizedResources(context, currentdocumentLocale).getString(R.string.finnish_language));

    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.document_spinner_item, spinnerLocale);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.document_spinner_dropdown_item);
    customerSelectedLanguageSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    customerSelectedLanguageSpinner.setSelection(0, false);
    customerSelectedLanguageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (customerSelectedLanguageSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(getLocalizedResources(context, currentdocumentLocale).getString(R.string.finnish_language))) {
                onLocaleChangedFi();
                initLanguageSpinner();
            } else if (customerSelectedLanguageSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(getLocalizedResources(context, currentdocumentLocale).getString(R.string.english_language))) {
                onLocaleChangedEng();
                initLanguageSpinner();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

By doing this it basically does what I need, but it also goes into an endless loop since the `onItemSelected` is always called after initialization, even when I do the `.setSelection(0, false)`. Is there a way to do what I need?

**EDIT**

So I tried creating a new `adapter` and then notifying it of changes.

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter;

private void initLanguageSpinner() {

    List<String> spinnerLocale = new ArrayList<>();
    if ((currentdocumentLocale.toString().startsWith("deviceNameFi") || currentdocumentLocale.getLanguage().equals("fi"))) {
        spinnerLocale.add(getLocalizedResources(context, currentdocumentLocale).getString(R.string.finnish_language));
        spinnerLocale.add(getLocalizedResources(context, currentdocumentLocale).getString(R.string.english_language));
    } else {
        spinnerLocale.add(getLocalizedResources(context, currentdocumentLocale).getString(R.string.english_language));
        spinnerLocale.add(getLocalizedResources(context, currentdocumentLocale).getString(R.string.finnish_language));

    }

    spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.document_spinner_item, spinnerLocale);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.document_spinner_dropdown_item);
    customerSelectedLanguageSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    customerSelectedLanguageSpinner.setSelection(0, false);
    customerSelectedLanguageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (customerSelectedLanguageSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(getLocalizedResources(context, currentdocumentLocale).getString(R.string.finnish_language))) {
                setSpinnerAdapter(customerSelectedLanguageSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()); 
                onLocaleChangedFi();
            } else if (customerSelectedLanguageSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(getLocalizedResources(context, currentdocumentLocale).getString(R.string.english_language))) {
                setSpinnerAdapter(customerSelectedLanguageSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                onLocaleChangedEng();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}

private void setSpinnerAdapter(String language){
    if(language.equals("fi")){
        String[] myListFinnish = new String[] { getLocalizedResources(context, currentdocumentLocale).getString(R.string.finnish_language), getLocalizedResources(context, currentdocumentLocale).getString(R.string.english_language)};
        spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.document_spinner_item, myListFinnish);
    } else {
        String[] myListEnglish = new String[] { getLocalizedResources(context, currentdocumentLocale).getString(R.string.english_language), getLocalizedResources(context, currentDocumentLocale).getString(R.string.finnish_language)};
        spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.document_spinner_item, myListEnglish);
    }
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.document_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This way it does not even change the list strings or order. `onLocaleChangedEng();` basically changes the `Locale` variable in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is a dead loop. and if the adapter item data changed, 
such as add, remove, clear by `adapter` you can use `notifyDataSetChanged`
method.

> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

```
adapter.clear()/add(object)/addAll();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

then the view will update but not init.

if the whole data changed, you can also recreate an adapter, and then set data

```
dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, newStringList);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerCategory.setAdapter(dataAdapter)
```

At the same time, you can also `clear` and `addAll`, then `notifyDataSetChanged`

```
adapter.clear() //remove all data;
adapter.addAll(source);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

//or remove it, then insert it in the first. that is acturl for your conditon
adapter.remove(objcet) //remove special data;
adapter.insert(object,index);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Secondly, you can also set a Tag to make when init the `onItemSelected` not called. the code like this:

```
//define a tag when first it is 0
int check = 0;
//then in the onItemSelected add a check condition
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos,long id) {
   if(++check> 1) {
      //do some things when item selected.
   }
}
```

use notifyDataSetChanged to update data, not every time init spinner. if you only want to remove the init selected effect, use the `check` tag.

Comment: But by doing it the first way.. How do you change the adapter.. do you just create a new one? Do I also need to add the `adapter.setDropDownViewResource(...)`.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: have you tried calling `spinnerAdapter.clear()` after calling `setSpinnerAdapter`, like what @Lenoarod mentioned earlier